# Not able to see Tomcat homepage when starting Tomcat 8.0.27 from IntelliJ Ultimate Edition on Mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've installed Tomcat 8 (using brew install tomcat) on Yosemite (Mac OS).

Using ./startup.sh and ./shutdown.sh I can start and and stop Tomcat just fine. When I navigate to http://localhost:8080, I can see the Tomcat homepage.

However, I'm trying to create a basic Hello World servlet in IntelliJ 15 Ultimate version (30 day trial), and have Tomcat home and Tomcat base to : /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.27/libexec

When I start the application server from within IntelliJ, everything looks ok, the server log says "Connected to Server" and its looking like the following startup command has been executed - /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.27/libexec/bin/catalina.sh run

I'm not confident everything is hanging together correctly because when I go to localhost:8080 there is no page served. Note at this point the Tomcat instance running from the terminal has been closed..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost:8080/manager` `localhost:8080/admin` and `localhost:8080/` urls are basically web applications which are available under the `TOMCAT_INSTALLATION_DIR/webapps/` directory. So when you start the tomcat using the startup.sh, it will by default use the `TOMCAT_INSTALLATION_DIR` as `catalina.home` and start to load all web applications under `${catalina.home}/webapps.`

However, IDEs like **intelliJ** and **Eclipse** may use a temporary location as catalina.home. Which means that the tomcat home page and manager application will not be available to load when the server starts. This doesn't stop your application from loading. You can still access them from http://localhost:8080/yourApp or some similar URL.

If you run the below jsp file under intelliJ, It will give you the actual location from which location your web application is running

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Absolute Path</title>
  </head>
  Absolute Path is:<%= getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %> 
</html>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I dont actually have a webapp to run yet. I'm fairly new to serlvets and jsps. All I'm trying to do at the moment is to run Tomcat from IntelliJ. If I can then navigate to localhost:8080 and see the Tomcat homepage, that would be success for me. I can then continue with the tutorial I'm going through. 

Thats the blocker for me at the moment. I feel like what I have is a configuration issue in IntelliJ..

Comment: Given that you haven't deployed any webapps, The tomcat would have initialized by IntelliJ without any webapps (Not even the home page and admin). So in this case you would get a `404 page not found` error from tomcat which would confirm that the tomcat is running.
Remember that the 404 error doesnt mean the server has problems but it doesn't find the page that you are looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear. It looks like Tomcat is running. I do 
ps -eaf | grep tomcat 
and I see a process coming up in the output.

The main problem here is that IntelliJ is opening up Chrome and when it goes to localhost:8080 there is a blank page, rather than the Tomcat homepage. 

sorry for any confusion.

any ideas why I might be seeing the empty blank page?

the output says Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.27/libexec/webapps/manager has finished in 198 ms

Comment: Hi Raja, yes after a bit of fiddling around with the tomcat-users.xml file I can now successfully access local:8080/manager

I can see the Tomcat Web Application Manager.  I have confidence that Tomcat is running smoothly...however what do I need to configure to allow me to see the usual Tomcat homepage at localhost:8080? 

I'm still a bit confused as to why the usual homepage doesn't display and what configuration I need to check for that?

Comment: I have created a new project in the following way on IntelliJ 15 Ultimate
File -> New Project -> Spring (left hand menu) -> Jave EE then selected Application Server

So - able to access localhost:8080/manager but not localhost:8080 any suggestions??